# Finding shortest path with SPARQL query

Tags: graph, sparql, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I am trying to understand the computational limitations of the SPARQL query, and I would like know how to write a query that will determine if there is a directed path between two objects.

I know a way to do it for a path of a specific length:

```
SELECT ?a ?b ?c ?d
WHERE { ?a  <http://graphtheory/hasNeighbor>  ?b . 
        ?b  <http://graphtheory/hasNeighbor>  ?c .
        ?c  <http://graphtheory/hasNeighbor>  ?d .
        FILTER (?a != ?c && ?b != ?d
                && ?a = <http://graphtheory/node/1>
                && ?d = <http://graphtheory/node/2>)
      }
LIMIT 10
```

Is there a way to search for any length path in a single query? Is this impossible with SPARQL?

Comment: Hi! I am looking for a similar solution, to identify the shortest path length between two nodes. Were you able to find any solution to this? maybe even using Breadth-first or depth-first search algorithms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AndyS gave all the elements to answer this question, but there are some typos that might make it hard to apply them.  As he says:

> SPARQL 1.1 has property path which includes the * operator for any number of.
>
> It does not tell you what the path is nor the length of the shortest path - only whether there is such a path.

The way to do this (based on AndyS, but with two little fixes) is:

```
PREFIX : <http://graphtheory/>
PREFIX node: <http://graphtheory/node/>

ASK { node:1 :hasNeighbor* node:2 }
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this without using property paths.

Answer (score 7):

SPARQL 1.1 has [property paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) which include the `*` operator for “any number of”.

It does not tell you what the path is nor the length of the shortest path—only whether there is such a path.

```
PREFIX : <http://graphtheory/node/>
PREFIX node: <http://graphtheory/node/>

ASK { node:1 :hasNeighbor* node:2 }
```

(You don't need the `?a =` and `?d =`, you can write the values into the query.)

Adding a `path` datatype into the language is a place for future work—a few experimental systems have taken a look at the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this cleans up the approach I took above a lot.  A minor issue in your solution is the PREFIX node: should be <http://graphtheory/node/> (I believe).  Once this change is made, your query returns true if there is an edge between node 1 and 2, but false if there is a path but not an edge.

Comment: To made the query return true when there is a path but not an edge, I added the * operator to the end of :hasNeighbor, i.e. "ASK { node:1 :hasNeighbor* node:2 }".  Is it possible to do this without property paths?