# find the distance between two nodes in an hierarchy in DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to fire a query using virtuso sparql server on dbpedia. Here I have two resources as an actor as **"dbpedia:Aamir_Khan"** and have an **owl:class Actors.** I want to find the distance between the Aamir khan page to the Actor class. In general I want to **find the distance between two nodes in an hierarchy in dbpedia**. I am new to this. I have seen several examples But none of them are directly using dbpedia resources. Please any one help in reference to an example using specific dbpedia ontology.

Comment: there isn't one sparql query to do that if the predicates that connect the two nodes are not the same type at each step. However, there are SPARQL tools out there that will iterate until an answer is generated. If steps that join the two nodes do, in fact, have the same type of predicate at each step, then you can run a query for property paths of one or more steps (e.g. unlimited steps). i'm sure someone will come around in a few minutes to explain that :)

Comment: Dear @Kristian..Thankyou for the reply. Can you please elaborate by giving any specific example in the case of  having the same type of predicate at each step.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388864/finding-shortest-path-with-sparql-query

Comment: more on the topic of property paths: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/1817/finding-the-shortest-route-between-two-concepts-using-sparql

Comment: and another: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/3491/how-can-i-calculate-the-length-of-a-path-between-2-graph-nodes-in-sparql

Comment: @Kristian You wrote "there isn't one sparql query to do that if the predicates that connect the two nodes are not the same type at each step."  Actually, you *can* do wildcards with SPARQL property paths.  E.g., `<>|!<>` acts as a wildcard, since every property is either `<>` or it's not (`!<>`).  (If there's a `:` prefix defined, this can be even shorter: `:|!:`.)